# Will Spark Streaming Contexts and DataFrame Operations Cause Worker Contention?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, streaming, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Say I have a Spark cluster with 1 Driver and 3 Worker Nodes. I start a new job that needs a streaming context (DStream) consuming messages off a Kafka topic, and I need multiple ('competing') consumer threads all consuming messages off the topic and doing some work with the messages they receive. This work that they do, is DataFrame intensive, meaning lots of DataFrame operations get called. As I *understand* the Spark landscape, anytime DataFrame operations get called, the Spark driver runs those operations on available Worker Nodes.

So given the following code and the cluster described above:

```
def createKafkaStream(ssc: StreamingContext,
        kafkaTopics: String, brokers: String): DStream[(String, 
        String)] = {
    // some configs here
    KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder,
        StringDecoder](ssc, props, topicsSet)
}

def consumerHandler(): StreamingContext = {
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))

    createKafkaStream(ssc, "someTopic", "my-kafka-ip:9092").foreachRDD(rdd => {
        rdd.foreach { msg =>
            // Now do some DataFrame-intensive work.
            // As I understand things, DataFrame ops must be run
            // on Workers as well as streaming consumers.
        }
    })

    ssc
}

StreamingContext.getActive.foreach {
    _.stop(stopSparkContext = false)
}

val ssc = StreamingContext.getActiveOrCreate(consumerHandler)
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

...I'm worried about contention (hanging/lag/slowness) on the Worker Nodes. Because it sounds like Spark and Kafka will figure out (based on partitioning) how many streaming consumer threads should be deployed to different Worker Nodes.

So in a 3-Worker Node cluster, you could conceivably have 3 streaming consumer processes running, but inside each of those processes, we could be calling DataFrame operations. **Since all the Workers have already been 'used up' to serve as streaming consumers, there's no Workers left to perform DataFrame operations.**

So I ask: **Is this a legitimate concern, or does Spark do some timeslicing magic to make sure Workers (that are acting as streaming consumers) never block or prevent DataFrame operations from contending with each other?** And, if it is a concern, what's the general solution? More Worker nodes?

Comment: There is not enough data to answer. Please show implementation of the function you call in foreach!